# Unity - Script generated mesh has incorrect lighting

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a script that breaks a cube into four equal triangular prisms, GameObject Panel being the original object shattered. Each prism is created completely by a script by assigning vertices and triangles to a blank mesh, and the original object is destroyed.

```
    // 2D Points which will connect to the center to form triangles
    List<Vector2> shatterPoints = new List<Vector2> {new Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f),
        new Vector2(-0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), new Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f)};

    // Generate each fragment
    for (int i = 0; i < shatterPoints.Count; i++) {
        GameObject Fragment = new GameObject("Empty"); // Create game object
        Fragment.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        Fragment.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        Vector3 point1 = shatterPoints[i]; // Grab the two edge points for this fragment
        Vector3 point2;
        if (i + 1 == shatterPoints.Count) {
            point2 = shatterPoints[0];
        } else {
            point2 = shatterPoints[i + 1];
        }

        Mesh FragMesh = new Mesh(); // Create the mesh

        FragMesh.vertices = new Vector3[] {point1 + Vector3.forward * 0.5f,
            point2 + Vector3.forward * 0.5f, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0.5f),
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, -0.5f), point2 - Vector3.forward * 0.5f,
            point1 - Vector3.forward * 0.5f};
        FragMesh.triangles = new int[] {1,0,2,  5,4,3,  0,5,3,  3,2,0,  4,5,0,  0,1,4,  1,2,3,  3,4,1};

        // Copy important properties from the original piece to the fragment
        Fragment.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = FragMesh;
        Fragment.transform.position = Panel.transform.position;
        Fragment.transform.rotation = Panel.transform.rotation;
        Fragment.transform.localScale = Panel.transform.localScale;

        Fragment.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = Panel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        FragMesh.RecalculateNormals();

        // Add force here later (and a rigidbody while you're at it)
    }

    Destroy(Panel);
```

Here are the pictures of the cube before and after shattering:

[Cube before shattering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifZkl.png)

[Cube after shattering and manual displacement of fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlGVJ.png)

Though I recalculate the normals of each fragment in the script, lighting appears to be incorrect. I am new to procedural mesh generation, so can anyone shed some light on this? (no pun intended) Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atrifacts you are seeing are due to smoothing groups being the same for all your newly created meshes. Sure way around it would be to create seperate verecies for each face, than unity will not try to smooth the edges,